# Google Data Transfer API in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Using the information at this link:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/quickstart/python

I can build a Python app that lists the applications for any particular user. However, while the documentation exists on how to initiate transfer requests, they are not in Python and are in URI format only.

For example:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers/insert

Is there any way to use Python to insert data transfer requests?

Answer (score 0):

The newOwnerUserId and oldOwnerUserId are not strings but numbers. Please obtain the 'profileId' with Reports API.

Comment: Sorry, I can not comment because I have not 50 reputation.